# What is the struct of Vehicle Package Manifest and the Software Package Manifest inside it?

Tags: autosar

[image]

In the SWS of UCM described there having a Vehicle Package Manifest which contains Software Cluster info. But I cannot find the definition of Vehicle Package Manifest in the TPS. only find this in the EXP_PlatformDesgin.

> - List of backend packages: a list of SWCL names
> - Dependencies: dependencies between Software Clusters that will    overrule the already defined dependencies in Software Package
>     Manifest. Typically used by vehicle systems integrator to add
>     dependencies related to vehicle systems that backend package supplier 
>     is not aware of.
> - Origin: uri, repository or diagnostic address, for history, tracking    and security purposes
> - Version
> - Vehicle target: vehicle description
> - Campaign orchestration: Below is a model example.

1. Why there is no definition of `Vehicle Package Manifest` in the TPS?
2. Why there having two `SoftwarePackageManifest` one in the
   `VehiclePackageManifest` and another in the `SoftwarePackage`? Is that the same thing?

**Update:**

> 1. Why there is no definition of `Vehicle Package Manifest` in the TPS?

I found the answer in R19-11 TPS_ManifestSpecification.

About the second question, I still didn't find a clear definition of `SoftwarePackageManifest.arxml`(The red one in the picture) in R19-11. I am trying to implement the `Packager` tool for both `Software Package` and `Backend Package`. So I need to figure out

What is the usage of `SoftwarePackageManifest`? Does it design for Backend or UCM Master?

Whether the `SoftwarePackageManifest.arxml` is generated before the tool **Packaging** as input or during **Packaging** as output.

Comment: As already mentioned, please wait until the next AUTOSAR release (planned for November 2019). It may provide you with answers to your questions.

Comment: Hi, @UweHonekamp I updated the question. Would you mind take a look?

Answer (score 0):

> ### D Packages distribution within vehicle (informative)
>
> #### D.1 Overview
>
> **To prepare next releases of this specification**, Update and Configuration Management
>   team appends to this specification its future image of packages distribution from a
>   backend into a vehicle and between different UCMs by sharing sequence diagrams.
>   **Intention of this appendix is to gather comments from Autosar community to ensure
>   future API’s quality. All described methods have to be later specified.**

You have to **read** the spec correctly ..

- This is not official spec but **informative** meaning unofficial
- open for discussion by the AUTOSAR community (AUTOSAR consortium and members)
- has to be specified later after discussion

Answer (score 0):

The Vehicle Package Manifest is represented by meta-class `VehiclePackage` in the TPS Manifest. Actually, the term “manifest” on the AUTOSAR adaptive platform describes a piece of ARXML that is supposed to be uploaded to the target and that conforms to the AUTOSAR schema.

This means that the AUTOSAR schema needs support for various manifest configurations and that is the reason why the TPS Manifest discusses the usage of various meta-classes within the AUTOSAR meta-model (from which the AUTOSAR XML schema is generated).

A `VehiclePackage` describes how specific `SoftwarePackage`s shall be installed. A `SoftwarePackage`, in turn, is just a “logistics” wrapper around a `SoftwareCluster`.